# Kohler toilet, mansfield lid replacement

Tags: bathroom, toilet

I moved into a house about a week ago and I'm trying to install a pressure-operated bidet (a Luxe Neo 320) in my upstairs bathroom toilet. I've done this before in my old place and figured I had everything under control, but when I removed the toilet seat I was expecting to find screws, not... well, this:

[image]

https://photos.app.goo.gl/S9yudLaBtwDzRmAV9

The plastic arrow bits look like they should move, but I've tried prying at them with a small screwdriver with no results and didn't want to break anything by forcing it too much. I need to get under these to attach the bidet to the screws underneath though. What's the play here? How do I finish removing the toilet seat?

For what it's worth, while the toilet itself is a Kohler, the seat is a Mansfield.

Comment: Do those small outside tabs do anything?  Can you post a picture of how the seat fits in those things?

Comment: They act as a quick remove/sliding mechanism. The tiniest parts act as a snap lock for the cover.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/iadhGX7UKgTkhv938
https://photos.app.goo.gl/b1jZAHwuxhkYwPL89
https://photos.app.goo.gl/CeNkQLKTY4zEfw6KA

Comment: It looks like the seat just locks/clips on them.  Is there any thing underneath on the bottom like nuts/studs/bolts?  Most toilets have holes for seat bolts that those clips seem to hide.

Comment: There may be a screw underneath the bit with the arrow on it. I did note that the clips seem to rotate, but again, I didn't want to break anything trying to remove them.

Comment: Since they look like plastic, try placing a hot wet cloth over one for a few minutes then try moving them.

Comment: You need to loosen the nuts at below the deck.